# C# Backgroundworker w/ multiple parameters not cancelling

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, cancellation

i'm using a backgroundworker with mutliple parameters.
The worker is working with my parameters.
But my problem is, I can't stop the backgroundworker.

```
....
BackgroundWorker workerGetAdvData;
workerGetAdvData = new BackgroundWorker();
workerGetAdvData.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(getAdvData.request_DoWork);

workerGetAdvData.RunWorkerAsync(clsComSettingMain); 

........


class ClsGetAdvData
{
    //open Serial Port with settings from clsComSettings class
    byte[] adv_request = { 0xF0, 0x02, 0x0D };   //Command for requesting advanced sensor data from PFC

public void request_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ClsComSettingMain clsComSettingMain = (ClsComSettingMain)e.Argument;
    string comPort = clsComSettingMain.comport;
    int baudRate = clsComSettingMain.baudRate;

    if (comPort != null && baudRate != 0)
    {
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(comPort, baudRate);
        serialPort.Open();

        while (true)
        {
            if (e.Cancel)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                serialPort.Write(adv_request, 0, 3); // Write byte array to serial port, with no offset, all 3 bytes
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

I'm trying to cancel the background worker with following code:

```
        private void MenuItem_Click_Serial_Stop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (workerGetAdvData.IsBusy) //check if worker is running
        {
            workerGetAdvData.CancelAsync();
        }
    }
```

}

But the worker does not stop. It it not working because of the paramters I use in the worker?

Kind regards
Bastian

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the your DoWork code you should be checking [BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
public void request_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    ClsComSettingMain clsComSettingMain = (ClsComSettingMain)e.Argument;
    string comPort = clsComSettingMain.comport;
    int baudRate = clsComSettingMain.baudRate;

    if (comPort != null && baudRate != 0)
    {
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(comPort, baudRate);
        serialPort.Open();

        while (true)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                serialPort.Write(adv_request, 0, 3); // Write byte array to serial port, with no offset, all 3 bytes
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You could have easily answered that question yourself by simply reading the `CancelAsync` method [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @BastiAn You welcome. If it works for you, you may consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer. This way you'll gain some reputation points and also more attention to your future questions.